# How to reset issue "The page is not redirecting properly" in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, error-handling

My site was builtin codeigniter and was running accurately yesterday, but now it showing this error mentioned in image, can anyone help how to overcome it please?

[image]

Comment: Code doesn't just "Stop working" Did you change something?

Comment: Show some code here.

Comment: ok i have to check my code, may be my partner changed code.

Comment: actually your page has gone in infinite redirection
this kind of errror comes when browser find unusual redirection

Comment: yes checking my function one by one, hope will find something helpfull.

Comment: I got the answer and have fixed, my validation and landing functions were continuously redirecting page on each other, Thanks every one for help. You saved my time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer and have fixed, my validation and landing functions were continuously redirecting page on each other, Thanks every one for help. You saved my time.